# How to calculate cumulative sum?

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I have data containing columns `biweek` and `Total`, I want to get cumulative sum on `biweek` basis. My data is like:

```
biweek  Total
0   3060.913
1   4394.163
2   3413.748
3   2917.548
4   3442.055
5   3348.398
6   1771.722
```

and I want to get output like :

```
biweek  Total
0   3060.913
1   7455.076
2   10868.824
3   13786.372
4   17228.427
5   20576.825
6   22348.547
```

So it there a possible way to achieve it?

Comment: You need `df1$Total <- cumsum(df1$Total)`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
# replace the second column for the cumsum of the initial second column
data[, 2] <- cumsum(data[, 2])
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this based on multiple columns? For instance, with data.tabel, based on multiple columns can be: `DF[, Cumm := cumsum(ColA), by=list(ColB, ColC)]` How about in dataframes?

Comment: Maybe you can sum multiple columns first, like `mtcars[, 1] + mtcars[, 2]`, and then apply `cumsum()`?